# Values inserted with the JavaScript "value" property are ineffective

Tags: javascript, terminology

Normally if I insert values to an HTML form's *input field* element via the JavaScript `value` property and would send the form, the form would be sent just fine, just as if I would fill in the data manually by typing/pasting.

```
document.querySelector("#prcf_input_name").value = "X";
```

But, I have a scenario (in a website I didn't build) in which form data added by `value` property isn't recognized and the form can't be sent with it (as-putted, at least).
What is the **term** to describe such a "protection mechanism" which prevents data filled with `value` to be effective?

Comment: it's called form validation. there's a lot of libraries to do it, and HTML5 added several form input attribs to enforce certain rules about for data; length, min/max, type, even regexp matching.

Comment: @dandavis thank you so much, I have asked several programmers about this issue so far and no one from those I have asked had a clue about what is this particular type of protection (i.e. that values inserted with `value` aren't recognized). Maybe you have any idea?